# possible? seek *partially known* folder name - split to variable - insert/execute in robocopy *destination*

Tags: batch-file, variables, directory, explorer, robocopy

I use gallery-dl to download pics from Pixiv.com. All of the below are run from Windows' .bat files.

I *manually* create a folder with only {user[id]}.

Example: Pixiv - Temp\24517

I then copy gallery-dl.bat (which calls on gallery-dl.exe and the related gallery-dl.conf, elsewhere) and a number of assisting .jpg files into that folder.

Example: Pixiv-Temp\24517\gallery-dl.bat

I've done this for over 5,000 users.

Running gallery-dl.bat from within folder configured for the below, passing a variable of the folder name will download the pics as well as saving a *.sqlite3 file to the folder 24517.

gallery-dl.conf

```
"directory": ["{user[id]}"],
```

The actioning part of gallery-dl.bat (listed in whole, below).

```
"C:\Users\AdminS6\gallery-dl\gallery-dl.exe" -d "..\..\." --download-archive "%~dp0GDB.sqlite3" "https://www.pixiv.net/en/users/%FOLDER%/illustrations"
```

The current .bat file in whole:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
pushd "%~dp0" || exit /B
move /y "..\Folder2.jpg" "..\Folder.jpg"
for %%I in (..) do set "FOLDER=%%~nxI"
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ("%FOLDER%") do set tmpFOLDER=%%a

"C:\Users\AdminS6\gallery-dl\gallery-dl.exe" -d "..\..\." --download-archive "%~dp0GDB.sqlite3" "https://www.pixiv.net/en/users/%FOLDER%/illustrations"

del "..\Folder3.jpg"
if not exist "GDB.sqlite3" move /Y "..\Folder4.jpg" "..\Folder.jpg"
if exist "GDB.sqlite3" del "..\Folder4.jpg" && del "..\Folder.jpg"

if exist "..\*.mp4" md "..\Reels" & move /y "..\*.mp4" "..\Reels\"
if exist "..\*.gif" md "..\GIFs" & move /y "..\*.gif" "..\GIFs\"
if exist "..\*.webp" md "..\WEBPs" & move /y "..\*.webp" "..\WEBPs\"

robocopy "..\..\%FOLDER%" "X:\11Web\gallery-dl\Pixiv - Temp\24517 -" *.* /e /move

TIMEOUT /T 1
popd
endlocal
```

I now plan to change gallery-dl.conf to {user[id]} - {user[name]}. This will result in a change to the destination folder being created now by gallery-dl. The original folder is left unchanged.

Example my original source folder: Pixiv-Temp\24517

Example gallery-dl new output folder: Pixiv-Temp\24517 - ケースワベ

gallery-dl.conf

```
"directory": ["{user[id]} - {user[name]}"],
```

gallery-dl.exe

```
"C:\Users\AdminS6\gallery-dl\gallery-dl.exe" -d "..\..\." --download-archive "%~dp0GDB.sqlite3" "https://www.pixiv.net/en/users/%FOLDER%/illustrations"
```

Not knowing how a {user[name]} will come out in Explorer folder naming, I am left to still manually create an original source folder with only {user[id]}. **I will continue doing this due to ease.**

The above noted change will present problems I would like to overcome:

1. When running gallery-dl, the pics from Pixiv will be downloaded to an Explorer folder name of {user[id]} - {user[name]}, while the original manually-created folder still hosts the gallery-dl and *.sqlite3 file. I need these combined.
2. When re-running/updating gallery-dl against the 5,000+ other folders, I will be left with 5,000 of one {user[id]} and 5,000 of the other {user[id]} - {user[name]}.

Robocopy has shown the most promise in solving these. When run in the below .bat, gallery-dl runs and all files from {user[id]} folder are moved to {user[id]} - {user[name]} folder, leaving {user[id]} folder empty and I just run a script that deletes all empty folders. This has the added benefit that the .sqlite3 files are all moved.

**MY ISSUE**: I have not yet been successful with Robocopy without having to

1. **explicitly name the path for the destination folder**.

Example works:

```
robocopy "..\..\%FOLDER%" "X:\11Web\gallery-dl\Pixiv - Temp\24517 -" *.* /e /move
```

Example doesn't work:

```
robocopy "..\..\%FOLDER%" "..\..\24517 -" *.* /e /move
```

which after passing a second variable would look more like:

Example doesn't work:

```
robocopy "..\..\%FOLDER%" "..\..\%FOLDERDESTINATION%" *.* /e /move
```

nor

2. I have no idea how to pass a variable from a folder name that is not known in advance {user[id]} - {user[name]}, but must be searched for within the above root folder.

---

If there was a way from within the .bat file to

1. Declare a variable that matches the current folder {user[id]} (Already done in the below).
   Example: 24517

and

2. And gallery-dl creates the new {user[id]} - {user[name]} and done its business, the .bat find and declare a variable that matches "{user[id]} -".

Example: **24517 -** ケースワベ

As such, I will always know the first half of any variable:

{user[id]} -

or in this case

24517 -

**Question is can the entire new folder name be searched for based on the known (Example 24517 -), a suitable secondary variable created equating to the new folder name, from only that?**

3. And is then able to pass this variable to Robocopy in order to successfully move all desired files?

Example:

```
robocopy "..\..\%FOLDER%" "..\..\%FOLDERDESTINATION%" *.* /e /move
```

That would be just smashing!

Any and all ideas/assistance are appreciated. Thank you in advance!

---

***Final result after applying successful answer from Stephan***

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
pushd "%~dp0" || exit /B
move /y "..\Folder2.jpg" "..\Folder.jpg"
for %%I in (..) do set "FOLDER=%%~nxI"
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ("%FOLDER%") do set tmpFOLDER=%%a

"C:\Users\AdminS6\gallery-dl\gallery-dl.exe" -d "..\..\." --download-archive "%~dp0GDB.sqlite3" "https://www.pixiv.net/en/users/%FOLDER%/illustrations"

del "..\Folder3.jpg"
if not exist "GDB.sqlite3" move /Y "..\Folder4.jpg" "..\Folder.jpg"
if exist "GDB.sqlite3" del "..\Folder4.jpg" && del "..\Folder.jpg"

if exist "..\*.mp4" md "..\Reels" & move /y "..\*.mp4" "..\Reels\"
if exist "..\*.gif" md "..\GIFs" & move /y "..\*.gif" "..\GIFs\"
if exist "..\*.webp" md "..\WEBPs" & move /y "..\*.webp" "..\WEBPs\"

for /d %%a in ("..\..\%FOLDER% - *") do set "FOLDERDESTINATION=%%a"

rem ECHO %FOLDERDESTINATION%

robocopy "..\..\%FOLDER%" ".\%FOLDERDESTINATION%" *.* /e /move

TIMEOUT /T 1
popd
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I understood your question right, this should help:

```
for /d %%a in ("..\..\%folder% - *") do set "folderdestination=%%a"
```

(Assumption: there is just one username per `%folder%` - else this will get only the last of them)

Comment: THAT...IS...THE MONEY!!!!!!!!!!!! THE CROWD ROARS!!!

Inserted your:

`for /d %%a in ("..\..\%FOLDER% - *") do set "FOLDERDESTINATION=%%a"`

To verify the return value for your variable, I chose to temporarily add

`ECHO %FOLDERDESTINATION%`

Sure enough, it returned as expected, the value for the newly created folder IAW {user[id]} - {user[name]}

`Example: 24517 - ケースワベ`

Modifying your variable into the robocopy line, all files are now in the same folder **24517 - ケースワベ**

`robocopy "..\..\%FOLDER%" ".\%FOLDERDESTINATION%" *.* /e /move`

OUTSTANDING! THANKS SO MUCH!! ;)

Comment: BTW, for anyone else interested, I created a separate .bat file w/ the below which deletes all empty folder and subfolders. Credit goes to https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/find-and-delete-empty-folders-windows/#rd

`for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%i" 2>NUL`